# Azure DevOps with PHP using Guzzle showing error

Tags: php, web-services, guzzle

I am trying to write a simple PHP application that will automate creation of workitem in VSTS from PHP with Guzzle. Here is my code but it's throwing error such as "You must pass a valid patch document in the body of the request".

Appreciate guidance to make this work. Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
require 'vendor\autoload.php';
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request;

$token = 'This is my token';
$client = new Client();
$body = '[{
  "op": "add",
  "path": "/fields/System.Title",
  "value": "$(Test Message)"
},
 {
  "op": "add",
  "path": "/fields/System.AssignedTo",
  "value": "User 1"
},
{
  "op": "add",
  "path": "/fields/System.Description",
  "value": "This is a description of the Issue created from PowerShell"
},
 {
  "op": "add",
  "path": "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority",
  "value": "1"
}]';

$body = json_encode($body,JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
// echo $body;

try
{
$response = $client->request( 'PATCH', 'https://myinstance.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/Cherwell/_apis/wit/workitems/\$issue?api-version=5.0', [
                    'auth'    => [
                        null,
                        $token
                    ],
                    'debug' => ['false'], //For debug purposes
                    'headers' => [
                        'Content-Type' => 'application/json-patch+json'
                    ],


                ],

            );

            print_r(json_decode($response->getBody(), true));
}
catch (RequestException $e) { print_r($e); }
```

Comment: I have modifified the code, but new error was shown such as "415 Unsupported Media Type"

Comment: As `$body` is already in JSON format, I don't know if you should `json_encode()` it again. I would also recommend that you don't build the JSON yourself, create the structure in arrays and encode it (it can save issues with invalid JSON format).